# Can cooper sfp be replacaed with optical sfp

Tags: optical-network-terminal

I have a server which has a 10G NIC with cooper SFP in it.

Can a cooper SFP generally replaced with an optical SFP without replacing the NIC in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general this is possible.
SFP/SFP+ slots and transceivers are specifically designed to allow you to swap the transceivers depending on your networking needs.

But there are some considerations to take into account.

1. As this is 10 Gb/s it is NOT a SFP slot, but a SFP+ slot. SFP+ slots physically accept  SFP transceivers, but most only work with a SFP+ transceiver. Some can take both types.
2. Some NICs are picky about the exact brand/model of SFP+ transceiver. They only accept certain compatible brands. Or they are limited in terms of maximum power-usage and/or power-dissipation by the SFP+ transceiver.
3. In some cases the NIC and the SFP transceiver may be technically compatible, but your OS can't handle that particular combination. Or it needs different drivers for that combination.

There is no generic rule what works and what doesn't. To determine what exactly is possible with your NIC you will have to consult the manual.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful